# Let's not [bounce] around

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I saw the [bounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bounce) tag a few minutes ago. Not sure what it means.

Its wiki says

> The action of sending something back in the direction it originated.
>
> ---
>
> May be associated with
>
> - email: "unknown sender" or "action not permitted". See [bouncedemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bouncedemail)
> - graphics: to ricochet an item in a display field

This is totally ambiguous.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. Its wiki says it could mean multiple things

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, it doesn't. FAIL!

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

You know that something is about bouncing around in the post. It's not useful.

#### Is the topic described even on-topic for the site?

It's ambiguous so I don't know if it's on topic.

Are you bouncing a ball? If so, off topic!

Let's burn it!

Comment: What does the last part in the quoted tag wiki refer to? [Game development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD_0SnlwxYw&t=11m4s)?

Comment: Could also refer to the opposite of [debounce], but that tag has no wiki or excerpt so who knows? ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey ugh

Comment: Let's [bounce] this tag back to where it came from

Comment: We need a [bounce]r for this tag.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: The [bounce] and [debounce] can be combined used on the question related to [Table Tennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_tennis). -:)

Comment: well, hopefully you have not forgot to retag those to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bouncedemail

Comment: There's another tag for bounced email: [email-bounces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-bounces) which has 59 questions whereas bouncedemail has 49. Oughta be a synonym...

Answer (score 32):

I vote burn it. Bounce means multiple things. Yes, it can mean to send things back where they came from, it could also mean "restart" in relation to a computer or specific process. Aside from a vague interpretation of making a ball bounce (which is *extremely* specific for a graphics programming category, [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation) would be a better tag here), I don't see how this describes anything programming related. I'm not aware of any tools that use this name, either, though I could be misinformed here.

It's not useful to classify on a programming site because it's got nothing to do with programming where there aren't better tags for the broader topic. Bouncing balls go under [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation), collision detection falls under [collision-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection), bounced emails are hard pressed to be on topic for Stack Overflow but even that has a [email-bounces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-bounces) (and a former [bouncedemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bouncedemail)) tag.

Comment: In embedded systems, there's also the common term "signal bounce", which refers to the electromechanical phenomenon that happens whenever one presses a button. These can be filtered out in software through something called "de-bouncing".

Comment: Ball bouncing needn't be graphics programming - it could be just physics modelling.  But I suppose it's a valid argument either way.

Comment: True, but I was just trying to give a few examples. It totally could be physics related thus confusing the intent further

Answer (score 8):

It looks like it's appropriate to burn that tag. Really, it's not at all specific; it's ambiguous.

Someone could say it's useful because it could add some information if the post has anything related to "the action of sending something back in the direction it originated". However, it's not a reason for maintaining that tag, since if it was, tags could be created for almost all words in the dictionary. Stack Overflow's tags must refer to specific programming topics. If there's a relevant topic which is strongly associated with the word "bounce", maybe a **specific tag** could be created for it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've now retagged all of the questions that were definitely about bouncing email to [email-bounces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-bounces) (and eliminated the tag [bouncedemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bouncedemail)).

The remaining questions appear to be most commonly about:

- “bouncing ball” physics
- overscrolling in UI
- easing animations
- “bounce rate” in SEO

Comment: You're specifically not supposed to go out and retag while a burninate request is active...

Comment: @Herohtar I didn't know that. Sorry. I've reviewed the [tag info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) now.

Answer (score -14):

## Do not delete this tag

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
> No. Its wiki says it could mean multiple things

Actually it says that if you mean another thing, you have to use another tag.
Only one meaning.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes. It says that question is about physics and more precisely about simulation of bouncing objects.

> Is the topic described even on-topic for the site?
> Are you bouncing a ball? If so, off topic!

Since when programming a bouncing ball became offtopic?
It's ontopic.

## Maybe rename it?

That's possible, but anyway, it's much simpler to rename existing tag and check 304 questions with it than delete it and think where we should add some replacement on physics questions as the latest would require to check all the questions.

Now renaming is out of scope in this question and I think another question is needed for rename. So for current question my answer is "don't delete".

Comment: Programming a sports game might be on-topic, but that doesn't mean `football` should be a tag.

Comment: This tag should be renamed to `bounce-animation`, `bounce-simulation`, `bounce-physics` etc. to make it unambiguous and physics-specific.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur, rename tag and delete tag are different requests. If you propose to rename tag, it should not be deleted.

Comment: @Qwertiy I meant if you want a `bounce` tag related to Physics, then create new tags with those names, the `bounce` tag should still be deleted anyway as it is ambiguous as it stands.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur, and who should check all questions whether they need this tag? Much simpler is rename existing tag and remove it from questions that don't match it. There are only 113 questions with [bounce].

Comment: @Qwertiy then change your answer to say exactly that, your answer is unclear and suggests that `bounce` is fine as is, which is why its getting downvoted.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur, updated once more.

Comment: If bounce gets its own animation, simulation, and/or physics tags, then what is there to stop the following additional related tags in case I want to program them into my game and need support? `yoink-animation`, `yeet-animation`, `jump-animation`, `fly-animation`, `land-animation`, `shake-animation`, `spasm-animation`, `spin-animation`, `dance-animation`, `twirl-animation`, `wag-animation`. Looking these up led me to find the following three tags that may need burninations and/or edits: `spinach`, `spinning`, and `shake`.

Comment: What are you reading? The tag does *not* reference physics or simulating at all, and it has 321 questions, not 113.

Comment: @Pluto where are the jiggle physics tag? Fire, fluid (with viscosity), gas physics?

Comment: @Herohtar, now it has only 88 questions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjyhK.png. Have you forgot to count questions only? UPDATE: I'm wrong, there are 304. 88 is unanswered.

Comment: @Pluto, where do you see animations im my answer?

Comment: @Qwertiy Someone had been doing some cleanup, which isn't supposed to be done while a burninate request is open. The first time I looked at it there were actually 345 questions with the tag, but by the time I went to write the comment it had already dropped to 321. I guess some more happened after I wrote it, because now it's at 303.